# How to fix '605: /lib/libc.so.6' error for Matlab in Linux?

Tags: troubleshooting, matlab

How to fix  '605: /lib/libc.so.6' error for Matlab in Linux?

When I start Matlab in Linux I get a "605 error" like the following

```
$ matlab
/usr/local/matlabR2010a/bin/util/oscheck.sh: 605: /lib/libc.so.6: not found
```

The Matlab version is R2010a. The OS is Ubuntu 11.10 32-bit.

Comment: Have you tried installing the `libc` library on the Linux machine? That will probably solve the issue.

Comment: If I search `libc` using Ubuntu 11.10's Synaptic Package Manager, it finds hundreds of potential matches. I'm wondering how to identify a few of them to try installing first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution on [MATLAB Answers](http://www.mathworks.nl/matlabcentral/answers/10134-usr-local-matlab-r2011a-bin-util-oscheck-sh-605-lib64-libc-so-6-not-found):

```
$ locate libc.so
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so
$ sudo ln -s /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /lib/libc.so.6
$ matlab
```

For MATLAB 2012, on Ubuntu 12.04, libc-2.13 is replaced by libc-2.15, so you link as follows:

```
$ sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so /lib64/libc.so.6
```